# open pop up window on map marker from outside map canvas after click an anchor tag in drupal 7 using gmap, location

Tags: views, 7, google-maps, location

I have installed location module, gmap module and views

1. created nodes of article type say 5 node with their location filled in.
2. created a views selecting gmap as display.
3. my nodes are listed on maps perfectly with their markers & also pops up right content.
4. now I created attachment with the view to show my nodes titles after the view as unformated list.
5. my nodes are listed well on the map as well as in ul li format beneath the map
6. i want that when i hover on any title outside of a map it should pops up the related node in the map .

If it is clear to you then please help if not then leave a comment

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please read [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints) article. Long story short - you know what you mean, what you want and what research you did. We don't.

Comment: (function ($) {Drupal.behaviors.gmap = {    attach: function (context, settings) {$('.view-content > .views-row').each(function(i){$(this).bind('click', function() {google.maps.event.trigger(Drupal.settings.gmap.auto1map.markers[i].marker, 'click');return false;});     $(this).bind('mouseover', function() {google.maps.event.trigger(Drupal.settings.gmap.auto1map.markers[i].marker, 'mouseover');return false;      });$(this).bind('mouseout', function(){oogle.maps.event.trigger(Drupal.settings.gmap.auto1map.markers[i].marker, 'mouseout');return false;});});}};})(jQuery);
done using above code